# How do you check whether prerender is working and can a dynamic resource be used for prerendering?

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I have been trying to use the prerender function of PWA but I can't figure out whether it is working or not. One way I found was to go to task manager and see whether a prerendering task is assigned there or not but I could not find it in my task manager.

Also does prerender require the pre-rendering resource to be a static resource or can it be dynamic?

```
<link rel="prerender" href="//example/${exampleDto.exampleId}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the prerender hint is going to be removed (https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/blink-dev/0nSxuuv9bBw), it doesn't work in latest versions of Chrome. There is an alternative solution https://nesteryuk.info/2017/06/05/service-worker-as-fallback-to-the-prerender-resource-hint.html